# Где ошибка в коде дискорд бота?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я делаю дискорд бота, и хочу чтобы он отвечал на доброе утро рандомной реакцией, но скрипт не работает, где здесь ошибка?

код отвечающий за это:

```
hello = ["доброе утро", "добрый день", "добрый вечер"]
reaction_1 = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
react1 = reaction_1
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content.lower()
    if msg in hello:
        if react1 is not None:
            react2 = random.choice(react1)
            await message.add_reaction(react2)
```

Comment: Можете в вопросе привести весь код? Но, скорее всего вы не указали декоратор для метода `on_message()`.

Answer (score 0):

Код сделал короче, но он работает. Не забудьте в начале кода прописать `import random`

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    hello = ["доброе утро", "добрый день", "добрый вечер"]
    reactions = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
    msg = message.content.lower()
    if msg in hello:
        await message.add_reaction(reactions[random.randint(1, 8)])
```

Comment: большое спасибо но я нашел решение немного раньше